# NHibernate and Group by to another class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by

I have a class plannedSalesInYear

```
 public class PlannedSalesInYear{
      Vehicle _vehicle;
      int _year;
      int _plannedSales;

      ... Fields as Properties ...

 }
```

Mapping of this class should be no rocket-science so I leave it out.
Now I want to select data for all vehicles resulting in a Dictionary.

The Dictionary should look like this:

```
 IDictionary<Vehicle, IDictionary<int, int>>
```

Is this possible using hibernate (preferred criteria api)?
I want to avoid Linq because of performance issues. So the dao should directly select to the Dictionary.

Thanks in advance Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two roundtrips

```
// get the results
IDictionary<Vehicle, IDictionary<int, int>> results = session.Query<PlannedSalesInYear>()
    .Select(ps => new { VehicleId = ps.Vehicle.Id, ps.Year, ps.PlannedSales })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(a => a.VehicleId)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => session.Load<Vehicle>(gr.Key),
        gr => (IDictionary<int, int>)gr.ToDictionary(a => a.Year, a => a.PlannedSales));

// initialize the vehicles
session.QueryOver<Vehicle>().WhereRestrictionOn(v => v.Id).IsIn(results.Keys.Select(v => v.Id).ToArray()).List();
```

or one roundtrip with more data

```
// initialize the vehicles
session.Query<PlannedSalesInYear>()
    .Fetch(ps => ps.Vehicle)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(a => a.Vehicle)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.Key,
        gr => (IDictionary<int, int>)gr.ToDictionary(a => a.Year, a => a.PlannedSales));
```